# PHP JSON_encode output

Tags: php, json

This is my first time using PHP and I am making a script that will output text in JSON format. However I am encountering problems with the formatting.

Can someone explain why my browser renders the following code as..

```
"1", 'b' => "2", ), array( 'a' => "1", 'b' => "2", 'c' => "3", ) ) ); ?>
```

instead of something like this?

```
[ 
  [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" } ],
  [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "c" : "3" } ]
]
```

Code:

```
<body>
<?php

echo json_encode(
   array( 
      array( 
         'a' => "1", 
         'b' => "2"
      ), 
      array( 
         'a' => "1", 
         'b' => "2", 
         'c' => "3"
      )
   )
);

?>
</body>
```

Comment: But I got properly like `[{"a":"1","b":"2"},{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, but the setup doesn't seem right.  Your PHP code isn't evaluated.  What happens if you put nothing but

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

into your file?  Does it show only the code or a long table with all kinds of infos?  If it's the former, then you need to find out how to get your webserver to interpret the embedded PHP code before sending it to your browser.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save file as `YourFile.php`
2. Run on Xampp server like `localhost/yourFile.php` , not like `D://File....bla bla`

Answer (score 0):

You saved your file as html.

Change your file from `FileName.html` to `FileName.php`